# Join / Concatenate .wmv files

Tags: linux, freeware

I have 2 .wmv files which are equal in codec information (windows media video 9 in 640x360 with 25 fps; windows media audio 2 in stereo with 44,1kHz and 16 bits per sample). I'd like to concatenate / join them, so that I get one file which plays the content of file 1 and then the contents of file 2.

I can only use free, preferably open, software, preferably available for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

[Asfbin](http://www.radioactivepages.com/asfbin.aspx) appears like it might be able to do what you are looking for.

Comment: Appears to be a Windows program?

Comment: @JoshP - look further down the page, there is a linux command line version.

Comment: You are correct sir :)